# Mining bitcoin using cudaminer?

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, gpu

I have started mining using an nvidia gtx 670m GPU. I have compiled cudaminer and started mining on the slush pool. However, during mining I always get results similar to:

```
accepted: 0/X (0.00%), xx.xx khash/s (booo)
accepted: 0/X (0.00%), xx.xx khash/s (booo)
accepted: 0/X (0.00%), xx.xx khash/s (booo)
```

where X is an increasing counter and xx.xx is the hash rate(usually between 75.00 and 100.00 khash/s). Is this related to networking, more specifically port forwarding? I am asking because the bitcoin-qt client managed to synchronize with the network.

Comment: You probably want to mine an scrypt based coin, such as litecoin or dogecoin. Bitcoin is practically impossible to mine without ASICs these days

Answer (score 2):

That means your results are being rejected. Most probably becouse someone else's found them before. Mining bitcoins at 100KH/s is useless, at 280GH/s 0.06BTC are mined daily so....

Comment: I am mining for educational purposes. I have found a thread that mentioned that the launch configuration of the miner was wrong. I've changed the credentials and pointed to another resource and now I am no longer getting the accept 0/X message, only the hash rate.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you're trying to mine bitcoins with Litecoin (scrypt) algorithm.